# Responsive Bootstrap Tables with a looped <tr>

Tags: php, mysql, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a table that displays rows of images from my database in each . When I created the table I decided that for every 6 items (images) I wanted a new . I now want this table to be responsive so I understand the value "6" can no longer be used. What can I use instead of this value to ensure the best fit for each device?

Current code:

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
 <table class="table" align="center">
 <tbody>
 <?php
 $count = 0;

 $ids =  join("','",$ar);  

  $query = "SELECT DISTINCT(parts_cats.Part_Type) FROM parts_cats ORDER BY Part_Type ASC";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  while ($show = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    if($count == 6) {
            $count = 0;
            echo "</tr><tr>";
    } ?>

  <td align="center" valign="middle">
    <p align="center"><img src="images/part_icons/hoverover/<?php echo preg_replace('@[^a-zA-Z0-9_:;\(\)\?\|\=!<>+*%-]@', '',$show['Part_Type']); ?>.png" width="130" height="130"  alt="">       </p>
    <p align="center"><?php echo $show['Part_Type']; ?></p>
  </td>

  <?php
  $count++;
 }
 ?>

  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: not using a table but use the grid system :) see the bootstrap documentation http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't know the width of the screen in PHP (because it is a server side langage), you have 3 solutions:

```
First:
```

You can give the image paragraph a css id and give it a specific width for each screen size using media queries

```
Second:
```

You can create a different PHP file that generates the image table, in you original page make an Ajax script that asks for the images from the second PHP file by giving him the screen size, the PHP file then sends back the images and you can put them according to the size (complicated solution)

```
Third:
```

You can store the list of images in a javasript array using PHP and viewing them inside the body, example:

```
<script>
  var images[];
  var i=0;
<?php
  $query = "SELECT DISTINCT(parts_cats.Part_Type) FROM parts_cats ORDER BY Part_Type ASC";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  while ($show = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
  echo 'images[i]="images/part_icons/hoverover/'.preg_replace('@[^a-zA-Z0-9_:;\(\)\?\|\=!<>+*%-]@', '',$show['Part_Type']).'.png"';
  i=i+1;
    } ?>
</script>
```